# MFXInit() in libmfx.a segfaults when called from shared object

Tags: c++, linux, intel-media-sdk

(While Intel's forum is a more natural place to ask [this question](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/551331) I'm posting it here hoping for more activity than Intel's total lack thereof -- so far)

I'm unable to create a dynamic link library that uses Intel Media SDK (linux server) to manipulate h264 video and noticed a problem in the design of the MFX library. The way I understand it, programs are supposed to link to *static* library, like:

```
$ g++ .... -L/opt/intel/mediasdk/lib/lin_x64 -lmfx
```

However, this `libmfx.a` library appears to delegate all calls to a `dlopen`ed *dynamic* library `/opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfxhw64.so`. It is worth noting that function **names** (and signatures) exposed by static and dynamic libraries are **identical**, which is kind of confusing and dangerous.

While I don't understand the rationale behind this design, it should not be a problem by itself were it not that apparently some static/global initialization from within the library causes havoc when the (static) `libmfx.a` is included in a shared object. Ie.:

```
    +------+     +-----------+
    | main | <-- | mylib.so  |
    +------+     |           |          +---------------+
                 | libmfx.a  | (dlopen) | libmfxhw64.so |
                 |          <-------------              |
                 |+---------+|          |+-------------+|
                 ||MFXInit()||          ||  MFXInit()  ||
                 ||...      ||          ||  ...        ||
                 ||         ||          ||             ||
                 +===========+          +===============+
```

The above library could be assembled like this:

```
$ g++ -shared -o mylib.so my1.o my2.o -lmfx
```

And then (dynamically) linked to `main.o` like so:

```
$ g++ -o main main.o mylib.so -ldl
```

(Note that the additional `libdl` is necessary to allow `libmfx.a` to `dlopen()` `libmfxhw64.so`.)

Unfortunately, upon the first `MFXInit()` call, the program causes a segmentation fault (accessing address 0x0000400). GDB backtrace:

```
#0  0x0000000000000400 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff61fb4cd in MFXInit () from /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfxhw64-p.so.1.13
#2  0x00007ffff7bd3a1f in MFX_DISP_HANDLE::LoadSelectedDLL(char const*, eMfxImplType, int, int) () from ./lib-a.so
#3  0x00007ffff7bd12b1 in MFXInit () from ./lib-a.so
#4  0x00007ffff7bd09c8 in test_mfx () at lib.c:12
#5  0x0000000000400744 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe0d8) at main.c:8
```

(Observe that `MFXInit()` at stackframe `#3` is the one in `libmfx.a` whereas the one at `#1` is in `libmfxhw64.so`.)

Note that there is *no* crash when `mylib` is created as a *static* library. Using breakpoints and disassembler, I managed to make following backtrace snapshot where in both cases `#1` is at `MFXInit+424`, but they appear to hit *different* versions of `MFXQueryVersion` (absolute addresses are meaningless due to relocation):

```
#0  0x00007ffff6411980 in MFXQueryVersion () from /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfxhw64-p.so.1.13
#1  0x00007ffff640c4cd in MFXInit () from /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfxhw64-p.so.1.13
#2  0x000000000040484f in MFX_DISP_HANDLE::LoadSelectedDLL(char const*, eMfxImplType, int, int) ()
#3  0x00000000004020e1 in MFXInit ()
#4  0x0000000000401800 in test_mfx () at lib.c:12
#5  0x0000000000401794 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe0e8) at main.c:8
```

Because both static and shared Intel libs expose the same API functions, I *can* link straight into `libmfxhw64.so` guts directly, but I suppose that bypassing the static "dispatcher" is without warranty(?)

Could someone explain Intel's idea behind said design? Spec., why provide a static library that only delegates to an `.so` that has identical interface?

Also, it appears that the SEGV is caused by static/global data in either `libmfx.a` or `libmfxhw64.so`. Is there a way to force a specific execution order on dynamically loaded static/global sections? What is the best approach to debug these kinds of problems?

---

Tested with Intel Media SDK R2 (ubuntu 12) and Intel Media SDK 2015R3-R5 (Centos 7, 1.13/1.15) on Intel Haswell i7-4790 @3.6Ghz

If you have a working Intel MSDK setup, please compile [my example code](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/fa/e5/intel-media-sdk-bug.tgz) to confirm the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(OK, since no one seems eager, I'll do the inelegant thing and post an answer to my own question).

After considerable research trying to break the unintentional circular linking, I discovered that the `ld` option `--exclude-libs` provides solace. Essentially, I was looking for a way to force removal of any `libmfx.a` symbols after using them to resolve dependencies in `lib.o` while creating the DLL. This could be accomplished by creating the `so` like this:

```
g++ -shared -o lib-a.so lib.o -L/opt/intel/mediasdk/lib/lin_x64 -lmfx -Wl,--exclude-libs=libmfx
```

Once the library is created like this, Bob's you uncle:

```
g++ -o main-so-a main.o lib-a.so -ldl
```

(Note that `libdl` is still needed because Intel's MFX (now inside `lib-a.so`) still uses `dlopen` to discover `libmfxhw64.so`)

From the `ld` man page:

```
   --exclude-libs lib,lib,...
       Specifies a list of archive libraries from which symbols should not be
       automatically exported.  The library names may be delimited by commas or
       colons.  Specifying "--exclude-libs ALL" excludes symbols in all archive
       libraries from automatic export.  This option is available only for the
       i386 PE targeted port of the linker and for ELF targeted ports.  For i386
       PE, symbols explicitly listed in a .def file are still exported,
       regardless of this option.  For ELF targeted ports, symbols affected
       by this option will be treated as hidden.
```

So, essentially the trick is no make sure that the relevant ELF symbols are marked *hidden*. Normally this would be handled through `#pragma`s by the library developers (ie. Intel), but due to their negligence this needs to be retrofitted in this case.

I suppose the same could have been accomplished with a `--version-script` map file, but that might have turned out to be more fragile since we want to fully encapsulate `libmfx.a` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

At the very end of the file "readme-dispatcher-linux.pdf" in recent releases of the dispatcher source code, there is this:

> There is slight difference between using Dispatcher library from
>   executable module or from shared object. To mitigate symbol conflict
>   between itself and SDK shared object on Linux*, application should: 
>   1) link against libdispatch_shared.a instead of libmfx.a
>   2) define MFX_DISPATCHER_EXPOSED_PREFIX before any SDK includes

I have used this, and it works to address the symbol conflict issue you describe.

You can find this file, if you install "Intel Media Server Studio Professional 2016". There is a free community edition. The source files and the PDF will be found at /opt/intel/mediasdk/opensource/